# How to insert URL parameter in DIV?

Tags: javascript, html

my code is

```
<a href="#" target="_blank"  class="floatLeft" onclick="change('http://localhost/allwidgets/widgets.html');" >

function change(url)
{
    alert(url);
    document.getElementById("mainOuter").innerHTML=url;
}
```

Actually I want that url  should go in innerHTML of mainOuter div and that page should display  in that.

Please suggest....

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you may actually want an [iframe](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp):

```
<iframe id="someIframe"></iframe>

document.getElementById("someIframe").src = url;
```

If you want to actually modify a DIV's innerHTML, then you need to use a AJAX request to get the desired HTML, then use innerHTML.  Libraries can make this easier.

Comment: not exactly 
u r right but i want that div should contain that user content as innerHTML

Answer (score 1):

You can't do like this.  There are to possible ways to do this.

***Method 1***

You can use an [**iframe**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535258(VS.85).aspx) and load the page corresponding to the url by giving iframe's source as the url.

***Method 2***

You can use [**.load**](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method of jQuery to load a page using the url. Something like

```
$('#mainOuter').load(url);
```